# How to Map a ManyToOne relationship from 2 sides with shared primary key

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have 3 tables : Employee, Imputation and Task.

1. each employee may have many imputations and an imputatino can belong
   to only one employee at a time ( ManyToOne relationship )
2. List each task may have multiple imputations and an imputation can only belong to one task at a time (ManyToOne relationship
3. I want the imputation table to have TASK_ID as its PRIMARY_KEY

here are my 3 entities :

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="employee")
public class AppUser {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
    private List<Imputation> imputations;
}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Imputation {
  
    @Id
    private String id; //something needs to be done here to have the id = task_id

    private LocalDate day;
    private Double workload;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name= "employee_id")
    private AppUser employee;
}

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
    private List<Imputation> imputations;

}
```

this is how i want my table Imputation to look like (as i said, task_id is a PRIMARY KEY AND a FOREIGN KEY ) :

```
task_id | day | workload |employee_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@Entity
public class Imputation {
  
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "task_id")
    private Task task;

    private LocalDate day;
    private Double workload;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name= "employee_id")
    private AppUser employee;
}
```

Or if you want to keep a string property in the entity:

```
@Entity
public class Imputation {
  
    @Id
    private String id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "task_id")
    private Task task;

    private LocalDate day;
    private Double workload;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name= "employee_id")
    private AppUser employee;
}
```

Comment: can you share a code where i can save a new imputation object? because it doesn't seem to work

Comment: is task new or existing? Not a fan of Spring api, but JPA EntityManager persist on a new Imputation instance will work if the other references (task and AppUser) are managed in the persistence unit. If Task is new, you must call persist on it first or modify the task mapping to cascade the persist call to it. What is the error you get?